# Sed: backreference substring from line matching regexp in 's' command

Tags: sed

I'm experimenting with sed and recently I've noticed interesting behavior. However, I'm unable to find any documentation that describes it.

Imagine that we have file called 'sedtest':

```
$cat sedtest
 hello 0 world
 example
 4 sed
 Phone number: 123-456-789
```

Next, I'll run it through sed:

```
$cat sedtest | sed '/\([[:digit:]]\+\)/s,,(\1),'
 hello (0) world
 example
 (4) sed
 Phone number: (123)-456-789
```

That was fairly easy to understand sed script:

1. First, it matches string by regexp `\([[:digit:]]\+\)`, which means "match string that contains 1 or more digits". Notice that I also use `s`-command-style `\(` and `\)` parentheses to mark substring here (is it allowed?).
2. In case of match it proceeds with `s` command `s,,(\1),` (with empty regexp field), that means "replace matched substring with `(\1)`".

Initially I thought that it should fail with error, because `\1` and similar backreferences should work only for substrings from `s` command matcher field, which is empty in this case.

But the result is as if it was `s,\([[:digit:]]\+\),(\1),` script (`\regexp\` matcher moved inside `s` command matcher field)!

So, the question is: is it normal (i.e. it is desired behavior) to backreference substrings of text matched by `\regexp\` rule from `s//replace/` command as if they were matched by `s/regexp/replace/` command?

**P.S.**

My sed version is: GNU sed 4.2.1

And motivation behind question is that way you can do something like:

`sed '/^Number: \([[:digit:]]\+\)$/{s,,#NUMBER: (\1),;p;d};q 1'`, i.e.

1. `/^Number: \([[:digit:]]\+\)$/` - match every string of kind `Number: 12345` and in case of match:

   - `s,,#NUMBER: (\1),` - replace it with `#NUMBER: (12345)`
   - `p` - print it
   - `d` - clear pattern space, and *start new cycle* (fetch new line and start parsing script expression from beginning)
2. `q 1` - exit with code 1. This command is executed only if no match occured in step 1 (because of `d` command presence) - it checks for 'not matched' case, which in my situation means 'not allowed string' and must result in error.

Main trick here was executing `p` and `d` commands after substitution took place, which is not possible when using 'normal' `s/match/replace/` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. The back reference hold space doesn't get cleared unless you do another match. Since your regex for `s` is null, `\1` refers to the capture group previous to that. You can see the difference:

```
$ sed '/\([[:digit:]]\+\)/s,\(a\),(\1),' sedtest
hello 0 world
 example
 4 sed
 Phone number: 123-456-789
```

Nothing matched (lines with digits which also have `a`, but the back reference holds were cleared

```
$sed '/\([[:digit:]]\+\)/s,\(e\),(\1),'
h(e)llo 0 world
 example
 4 s(e)d
 Phon(e) number: 123-456-789
```

`e` matched and that becomes the back reference.

If you don't want this behaviour, you shouldn't create the back reference by putting `\( \)` around `[[:digit:]]` in the first place.